# Do I have to use an explicit match statement to identify its wildcard value?

Tags: f#

**Do I have to use an explicit match statement to identify its wildcard value?**

For example, take the following function:

```
let (|Positive|Neutral|Negative|) = function
    | x when x > 0 -> Positive
    | x when x = 0 -> Neutral
    | x when x < 0 -> Negative
    | _            -> failwith (sprintf "unknown: %d" _)
```

**Error:**

> Unexpected symbol '_' in expression

I learned that I can do this without any errors:

```
let (|Positive|Neutral|Negative|) v =
    match v with
    | x when x > 0 -> Positive
    | x when x = 0 -> Neutral
    | x when x < 0 -> Negative
    | _            -> failwith (sprintf "unknown: %d" v)
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the result from a posted answer:

```
let (|Positive|Neutral|Negative|) = function
    | x when x > 0 -> Positive
    | x when x = 0 -> Neutral
    | x when x < 0 -> Negative
    | x            -> failwith (sprintf "unknown: %d" x)
```

Comment: Think of underscore as ignore/discard. It's a special symbol that can never be assigned a value (except maybe from another .NET language?)

Comment: It's a perfectly valid identifier for variables, methods etc. in C#. This special meaning is unique to F#. (VB.NET apparently doesn't let you use it as an identifier either, despite not having this kind of pattern matching.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it to this and it will work:

```
let (|Positive|Neutral|Negative|) = function
    | x when x > 0 -> Positive
    | x when x = 0 -> Neutral
    | x when x < 0 -> Negative
    | f          -> failwith (sprintf "unknown: %d" f)
```

Comment: Thanks. I learned that I can just remove the wildcard completely and just use f

Comment: yeah I totally missed that, when I was writing it